# Можете объяснить как идет разделение MVC?

Tags: php, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования

Я не очень хорошо понимаю, где границы каждой сущности в паттерне MVC.
Рассмотрим паттерн на примере PHP.
В типовом проекте у нас есть БД, php скрипты и html файлы.

По шаблонам вопросов нет - это html файлы с вставками кода (php, код шаблонизатора).

**А что такое модель и где её границы? Модель это БД? Или модель это БД и php скрипты работающие с ней?
А что тогда контроллер?**

Читал примеры и определения на многих сайтах и так и не смог найти границу между моделью и контроллером.

Википедия

> Модель предоставляет данные и методы работы с ними: запросы в базу
> данных...

Данные - то есть БД. Но и методы и запросы - то есть наши скрипты с классами, методами, запросами.

> Контроллер обеспечивает «связь» между пользователем и системой.

Но и это наши скрипты - ведь они, по сути всё и делают - пишут в бд, выводят из бд.

Answer (score 2):

Всё познаётся на практике и вряд ли можно всё объяснить в ответе. Самое сложное - это модель. Поэтому начнём с контроллера.

Контроллер, да, как и написано -  обеспечивает «связь» между пользователем и системой. Он должен принять запрос от пользователя, далее, в идеальном мире, дёрнуть какой-то метод "откуда-то" и, если нужно, вернуть ответ пользователю. В контроллере не должно быть никакой логики, как бизнес, так и простой. Все вычисления, логика, обработка данных, пересчёты, занесение в БД и пр, должно быть "где-то ещё" и результаты вернуть в контроллер, если это нужно для отдачи пользователю. Они такие должны быть по разным причинам, в т.ч. по причине что есть еще "Тестирование" и тестировать контроллеры сложно или невозможно порой. А вот тестирование логики в "чистом классе" вполне себе возможен. Проще мокать, стабать и прочие страшные вещи.
Ещё в контроллере не должно быть логики и прочего взаимодействия с со слоями системы, т.к. это будет нарушать множество принципов: **S** из принципа  **S**OLID, наверняка ещё и DRY будет нарушать, когда будут методы create/update, а также невозможно будет соблюсти модульность и сделать какой-то код независимый от MVC  фреймворков в принципе. Слишком большая зависимость.

С моделью тоже тяжело. Если брать по ооооочень упрощённому и, например, фреймворк *Yii2*, то можно считать, что модель - это то, где происходит работа с БД, т.к. там модель - это **буквально отражение записи в БД**. Там же, в плохих руках, происходит и какая-то логика приложения (потому что люди не знают, что можно писать код по-другому). Однако модель - гораздно сложнее понятие. В идеальном мире модель - то, где происходит какая-то бизнес логика приложения, очень грубо сказано, конечно (Вбейте в поисковике *DDD (Domain Driven Design)*). Всё что происходит в моделе в таком контексте - не зависимо ни от фреймворка, ни от MVC, ни от чего-либо ещё.

---

То есть если немного подвести итог: модель - реализовывается бизнес логика, "чистые классы", которые подвергаются тестированию. Контроллер - берёт запрос от пользователя, с помощью впомогательных функций "очищает их" и проверяет (валидирует), направляет в модель, где происходит вся основная логика. Из модели, если нужно, возвращаются данные в контроллер и из контроллера обратно пользователю.  Работа с БД в таком подходе происходит в РЕПОЗИТОРИЯХ, ссылки на которые находятся в модели. (Сейчас вас ещё больше запутаю )

В более непрофессиональных кругах  модель - там где происходит **и** бизнес-логика **и** работа с БД и что ещё можно вообразить. Но контроллер всё равно всегда занимается своего рода распределением обязанностей. Например направить в одну модель → получить данные → направить во вспомогательный сервсис → получить даннные → отпраивть пользователю.

В ещё больше непрофессиональных кругах всё подряд пишут в контроллере

---

> так и не смог найти границу

Как я писал - это происходит только с опытом. Начните с того, чтобы не писать никакой логики в контроллере, только "дёргать" вспомогательные сервисы и распределять работу между ними.

Если начать писать по *DDD*, то будет ещё сложнее определять не только эти границы, но и границы между слоями для того или иного действия

Comment: спасибо за подробный ответ - сохраню его себе. На примере новостного сайта. Вид - страничка шаблона с ссылкой прочитать новость №1. Контроллер - php скрипт, который принимает параметр 1 и вызывает метод ShowNews(1) у класса News. Класс News + БД - это модель. Итого контроллер - скрипт который только вызывает метод (методы) и возвращает, то что метод вернул. Модель - это БД + php скрипты с классами, запросами, какой то логикой. Так?

Comment: "*Итого контроллер - скрипт который только вызывает метод (методы)*" --- да. только это тонкий момент. Можно увлечься и начать вызывать один метод, второй третий и в итоге увеличить знание контроллера о логике приложения.  **в идеальном мире** это может сводиться вообще к вызову одного единственного метода модели (в профессиональной среде спрос с **сервиса**).Поэтому с этим надо осторожно........По поводу модели - если упрощённо, чтобы не ломать мозг - да, примерно так.